# Configuration needed so that sudo doesn't have to be typed before commands

Tags: command-line, sudo

How would I go about setting up my system so that `sudo` doesn't have to be typed before commands. For example instead of typing `sudo apt-get install` I would only have to type `apt-get install`. Now I know I can run `sudo -i` but I end up forgetting to do it half of the time. Is there a more permanent way of doing it? 
EDIT: For clarification I am not wanting to know how to do it without a password I already have that setup. I want to do it without typing the word `sudo` I want to remove the need to even type the word `sudo`.

Comment: you have a /etc/sudoers file where you can give users/groups permissions. See this: https://www.garron.me/en/linux/visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor.html.

Comment: Explain please?

Comment: But what would I have to put in the sudoers file to do what I am asking?

Comment: The link makes it pretty clear, did you read that?

Comment: Read `man sudoers`. However, reducing your system security so you don't have to type an extra 5 characters is unwise. Take advantage of bash history, and, if a command fails due to lack of `root`, do `sudo !!`

Comment: @AshwinGupta `sudoers` can be configured to remove the need for a *password* - but that doesn't remove the requirement to type `sudo` before the command

Comment: @steeldriver yeah sorry I misinterpreted the question. I don't know of a way to remove the need to type sudo.

Comment: I really don't care. I have backups. I just want to know!

Comment: Not duplicate... The OP wants to NOT use `sudo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this answer is not going to be popular, but in answering the question, it is appropriate (***but not wise***).

If you do not want to have to type `sudo` before everything which needs ***root*** authentication or authorization, then the only solution is to log in as root. This is **EXTREMELY** (I wish I could make it even bolder) and I repeat **EXTREMELY** unwise, and I think you will find yourself in much more of a bind than just having to remember to type the five characters `sudo` before your command.

As an alternative, you could `sudo su -` before you have to run a string of commands limiting the stress on your fingers for those extra five characters (*5's can add up quickly...*) and remember to type the four characters `exit` at the end so you do not do anything stupid unintentionally...

As was posted before, the better option is to just take advantage of the command history if you make a mistake and do:

```
$ make "me a sandwich"
No
$ sudo !!     # !! takes the full last command in history and puts it here
sudo make "me a sandwich"    #bash automatically shows you what the full command with replacement is...
Ok - Sandwich made
$
```

...

So, have fun and please root responsibly...

Comment: Really appreciate the simple mention of it being unwise, there is nothing worse than a 40 minute tirade answer about why someone shouldn't do something the speaker has almost no knowledge of...